# how to register custom FailureHandler in custom filter spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I made a custom filter and failureHandler. But to make it work i need to register handler in filter. So i willd be glad if someone will write how to do it in my code. I know that there are a lot of examples in stackowerflow but i'm new to spring and java and to understand how it works i need an example for my app. Please don't answer with "this is a duplicate".
My filter:

```
@Component("MyAuthFilter")
public class MyAuthFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private int errCode = 5;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        System.out.println("running my own version of UsernmePasswordFilter ... ");

        String login = (String) request.getParameter("login");
        String password = (String) request.getParameter("password");
        errCode = validate(login, password);
        System.out.println(login + " - " + password);
        System.out.println(request.getQueryString());           
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login, password);
        // Allow subclasses to set the "details" property
        setDetails(request, authRequest);
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }

    private int validate(String login, String password) {

        if (login.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()) {
            return 4;
        }
        if (login.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
            return 2;
        }
        if (!login.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()) {
            return 3;
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

here is my handler:

```
public class LoginFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    public LoginFailureHandler() {
        System.out.println("i debug");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

           System.out.println("do smth");
            super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);

    }

}
```

and my spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="com.webproject.LoginFailureHandler" />

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/courses*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <custom-filter  before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="MyAuthFilter" />
        <form-login
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/courses"
            username-parameter="loginField"
            password-parameter="passwordField" 
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
        />
        <csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="ars" password="1234" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare to beans and autowire them to your filter

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationFailureHandler getFailureHandler(){
  SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler handler  =  new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
  handler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login.html");
  return handler;
}
```

MyAuthFilter

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManager")
@Override
public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler) {
    this.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    this.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler);
}
```

Comment: in a configuration class, or you could just mark your handler with @component

Comment: i use xml files and i've already declared it like :
`<beans:bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="com.webproject.LoginFailureHandler" />

Comment: that should suffice

Comment: now it shows an error that  No qualifying bean of type AuthenticationFailureHandler available

Comment: means spring could not find your bean. something to do with your spring-security.xml: defined.